# Computer not starting, diagnostic stuck on HDD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, dell-inspiron, wubi

Please excuse my typing; because my computer is not working, I am on an iPod touch.

I tried to boot up my Dell Inspiron laptop, but it freezes and shows a blank screen after the Dell load screen finishes.

I then used F12 to run a full systems diagnostic, but it seems to be stuck at 95% on the Hard Drive. Now, the computer isn't important, but there are some extremely important files on my Hard Drive that I absolutely need recovered.

I'm just lost, and irritated. This all happened after I downloaded Wubi, the Ubuntu Windows-host software. To the best of my knowledge, Wubi was supposed to be entirely harmless. All I ask is that I access my Hard Drive files and save them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a live ubuntu disk you can easily pull your files off, given the drive is healthy. If the drive is failing and has mounting problems etc, using tools like dd or ddrescue can be used to get as much raw data as possible before it craps completely.

Grab your files and then scan the drive with the manufacturers diagnostic utility to make sure this is an HD problem and not something else. You can then work up a solution from there.